# Fragment lifecycle when using TabLayout from Design Support Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am using TabLayout from the new Design Support Library and the issue I am having is that I cannot control how content can be loaded or destroyed upon switching to each tab because all of them seem to be instantiated in memory.

I placed Log messages on my second tab on my override onPause, onResume methods and only switched between the first and third tabs and also tried switching away from the app and back. It seems that the Fragment Lifecycle does not exist and only the Activity lifecycle is what is being used for the fragments within each tab. Is there any way I can get knowledge of when the tab is selected within the Fragment?

Comment: Since `TabLayout` has nothing to do with Fragments or how they are displayed, I assume you're using a `ViewPager` along with your `TabLayout` to actually show your fragments?